# Django User Profile doesn't update

Tags: python, django, django-users

I am setting up a website in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), where users can see their profiles and update details (like email, password, etc) or delete own account. But updating the form is not acknowledged at all by the user. I am using the standard built-in User model.

**forms.py:**

```
class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','password','is_active')
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    form = UserDetailsForm(request.POST or None,
                       initial={'first_name':user.first_name,
                                'last_name':user.last_name,
                                'email':user.email,
                                'password':user.password,
                                'is_active':user.is_active,})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.save()
            messages.info(request, 'This is a debug message')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account'))

    context = {"form": form}

return render(request, "iFood/user-account.html", context)
```

**user-profile.html:**

```
...
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'account' %}" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Edit and Save">
            {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: You never associate the `user` with the `form`, and you never save the data that's submitted in the form, so why would you expect something to happen? `user.save()` just saves the user object, unchanged. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to see how to specify the instance for the form and to save it.

Comment: Also note that you cannot display and change a user's password this way. First, you don't have the user's password (luckily!) if you're using Django standard auth. Second, if the user changes the password, you need to save it as a hash using the `set_password()` method on the `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't change a password like that. You should take the password that user entered and set it with `user_obj.set_password()`:

[Django docs: Change password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)

And for your form:

You doing it wrong with `user.save()`. There is nothing to save for user object. You should save the form using `form.save()`.

Also `request.user` is the actual user object not the username.

forms.py:

```
class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email'','is_active')
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    form = UserDetailsForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the changes but password
            form.save()

            # Change password
            new_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            if new_password:
                user.set_password(new_pass)
            messages.info(request, 'This is a debug message')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account'))

    context = {"form": form}

    return render(request, "iFood/user-account.html", context)
```

Comment: But then the OP also has to initialise the form correctly with the user instance.

Comment: @dirkgroten Not sure if django even cares about that (never tested it) but i edited it out. Thanks.

Comment: I meant you need to pass the `instance=user` to the form initialiser, instead of `initial={...}`. Otherwise the `form.save()` will attempt to save a new `User`.

Comment: Yes, missed that too. added.

Comment: `initial` is redundant, if there's an `instance` the values will be filled with those of the instance initially.